# is it a good way to store 500 records locally in mobile

Tags: android, optimization, memory-management, local-storage

i am developing  mobile application and there is requirement for fetching records when it is connected to network (wifi/gprs) and store it locally. there may be huge data's (**500 records**) we need to store locally. why they are storing is they want it to show when the app is in offline mode. so my question is is it a good way to store this huge data locally in mobiles? will it effect the app performance ?

Comment: 500 Records mean nothing! What is a size of a record ? BTW you probably need to save those record in a data base. Data will not affect app performance if those data are not save in RAM

Comment: working on share market app. so 1 record means 1 transaction details done by a user. such 500 records. ther wont be any issues if store it in db.   will there be any issue in low end smart phones. actully i am working on cross platform mobile app development. so i have to consider 4 platform (android, ios, windows & BB). please advise

Comment: If you plan on using legacy BB (6 and 7) beware that they are very temperamental with databases. Refusing to work if no sdcard (of a specific type) is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can say is, depends. 500 really does not sound like a lot, but how big is each record, and how frequently will it update? Will it occur during run time, or will it be only during start up?

There are probably too many factors to give an accurate answer here. But yes, it will impact performance. The download time and database writes will be noticeable, especially if you plan on clearing the whole table and re-inserting every time. That said, it will likely be in the order of a few seconds.

My issue with pulling the whole dataset each time is it will result in unnecessary network traffic, which eats the battery, and is just a waste of bandwidth (which hits certain users hard).

If you have control over the server, you could look into keeping the dates of changes in the data. Then your call to the server will only return the rows that changed since your last update, meaning you only pull, insert, and delete a fraction of the dataset at a time.

Comment: 500 records will be key value pair from service response. this will be some string values.

Comment: Then you have nothing to worry about, you'll be looking at a few kilobytes.

Comment: Thanks Kevin & Neige